# Configuring 1:1 Nat using Firewalld for VM's

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, nat, centos7, bridge

I've setup 2 vm's within my server and I'm trying to setup a 1:1 NAT for them with firewalld on CentOS 7. Currently both vm's are behind a virtual bridge (virbr0, vnet0, vnet1) and I've made copies of the NIC for each IP to be used with them. I would like to set it up like this:

eth0:0 (public IP) -----> vnet0 (internal IP); 
eth0:1 (public IP) -----> vnet1 (internal IP)

The way I understand it is I'm looking for a 1:1 NAT but I'm not sure how to set it up. I had originally configured everything with a bridge but the hosting provider does not allow for the bridge on the network, the imaginary mac's of the virtual nic's get everything kicked off the network.

I've tried a few things but I'm not super comfortable with firewalld yet.

Comment: So here's what I've done so far, ultimately I'm trying to get these VM's to have public IP's. That's my main concern.

I've setup 2 virtual bridges (virbr1, virb2)  each of these has it's own VM. And they're setup with nat like this:   eth0:0 --> virbr1 --> vnet0;   
eth0:1 --> virbr2 --> vnet1   Everything makes it out ok, but when I try to ssh into the IP that's assigned to eth0:0 I'm still getting the main server.

Answer (score 10):

NAT is done at the firewall/router level.

Depending on your firewall/router you can setup 1:1 NAT's the only thing to keep in mind is you can only setup one port to one IP.

So if you have 2 web servers one will have to run a different port (other than 80) for the NAT to work.

Comment: Is there a way to just have it so it's interface to interface instead of port forwarding? Or IP to IP?